# Combining daily averages for different time periods in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with hourly entries for multiple products dating back to 2 years. I am trying to write a query which would look something like this:

```
PRODUCT, TODAY'S AVERAGE, LAST MONTHS DAILY AVERAGE, YEAR TO DATE DAILY AVERAGE
```

I am able to achieve this by writing separate queries for each of the averages and then joining them on the `PRODUCT NAME`. However, I want to be able to do the same, by writing one single query.

Is their a standard algorithm/method that I can apply?

Comment: Can you give us your queries plz

Comment: Can you give the definition of your table?

Comment: If you already have something that works then why are you looking for an alternative? What problems do you have with your current solution that you would like to solve?

Comment: What version of SQL-Server are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL 2005, and the reason i am looking for alternative is to reduce the JOINS.

The Table Definition is: TIMESTAMP, PRODUCTNAME, VALUE1, VALUE2

TimeStamp stores in the format: 1/1/1900 1:00 AM
ProductName is a varchar(16) value.
Value1 and Value2 are rounded to 2 decimal points.

I current do:

(SELECT ProductName, VALUE1
FROM TABLE
WHERE TIMESTAMP = {fn NOW()} )

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT ProductName, AVG(VALUE1)
FROM TABLE
WHERE TIMESTAMP BETWEEN (LAST MONTHS START AND END TIMESTAMP)

Comment: I current do:

SELECT A.ProductName, [CURRENT VALUE], [LAST MONTHS AVG]
(SELECT ProductName, VALUE1 AS [CURRENT VALUE]
FROM TABLE
WHERE TIMESTAMP = {fn NOW()} ) A

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT ProductName, AVG(VALUE1) AS [LAST MONTHS AVG]
FROM TABLE
WHERE TIMESTAMP BETWEEN (LAST MONTHS START AND END TIMESTAMP) ) B

ON A.ProductName = B.ProductName

GROUP BY ProductName
ORDER BY ProductName

Answer (score 0):

This is an aggregation query.  However, it gets variables for each of the time periods you want, and sums by day to do the final calculations.

```
select product,
       sum(DailySum*IsToday) as Today,
       sum(1.0*DailySum*IslastMonth) / sum(IslastMonth)
       sum(1.0*DailySum*IsYTD) / sum(IsYTD)
from (select product, cast(dt as date) as thedate, sum(val) as DailySum
             (case when cast(dt as date) = cast(getdate() as date) then 1 else 0 end) as IsToday,
             (case when year(dt) = year(dateadd(month, -1, getdate()) and month(dt) = month(dateadd(month, -1, getdate())
                   then 1 else 0
              end) as IslastMonth,
             (case when year(dt) = year(getdate()) tehn 1 else 0
              end) as IsYTD
       from t
       group by product, cast(dt as date)
     ) t
     ) t
```